# code look and its dis-/advantages?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i ve this code which is selection sorting but i ve written it pretty weird. So could you guys maybe tell me how to rewrite it without changing the whole structure of the code. 
And i wanted to ask in generall what are the dis-/advantages of having a nice written code?(beginner here)

```
def convertListType(li):
    li = [float(x) for x in li]
    return li

def findMin(li):
    x = li[0]
    for i in range(len(li)):
        if x > li[i]:
        x = li[i]
    return x

def selectionSort(li):
    for couter in range(len(li)):
        li[couter:couter]=[li.pop(li.index(findMin(li[couter:])))]

li = convertListType(input('Enter your numbers with a space  between.\t').split())
selectionSort(li)
print(li)
```

I know the last last line of the selectionSort ist dammn weird. :)

Comment: You can swap the values at two indices like this: `li[i], li[j] = li[j], li[i]`

Comment: If your code is working, you might get a better response at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (but you should make sure you explain more clearly than you did here, if you do want to ask there).

Comment: OK thanks guys, i  ll try it there